# Button not clickable through javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I want to click a button (see attached) with javascript, in chrome console, but it doesn't work. I tried with ID and Class but no chance. If I want to click on an a element on the same site it's working fine with both lines.[image].

What I tried:

```
document.getElementById('account-settings-save-button').click()
document.getElementsByClassName('btn-progress btn btn-primary icon-btn icon-right IDLE null')[0].click()
```

Comment: Can you create a snippet reproducing the issue?

Comment: How do you know it is not getting clicked?

Comment: I am watching the website and nothing happens when I click the button through the console.
I am not sure how I could produce a snippet due to it is a webpage in a member area.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes click won't work for example if you use it on `<a>` tags it won't trigger link. You can try using [MouseEvent API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent) to simulate click event.

Here you can find nice example [How to simulate a click event with vanilla JavaScript](https://gomakethings.com/how-to-simulate-a-click-event-with-javascript/)

In short, what you can try doing is:

```
//From the example above
var simulateClick = function (elem) {
    // Create our event (with options)
    var evt = new MouseEvent('click', {
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: true,
        view: window
    });
    // If cancelled, don't dispatch our event
    var canceled = !elem.dispatchEvent(evt);
};

var buttonToClick = document.getElementById('account-settings-save-button');
simulateClick(buttonToClick);
```

var buttonToClick = document.getElementById('account-settings-save-button');
simulateClick(buttonToClick);

Comment: I get an error document.getElemenyById is not a functin

Comment: Oh, I didnt saw either XD Now I don't get an error, but the button isn't clicked. Basically like before.

Comment: Can you find in the source code of the page where they are catching this button click and post that? @Tim

Comment: How can I do that? Sorry I am a total beginner... :/

Comment: Open your developer tool in the browser and go to sources tab there you can find project files, maybe you can find js that they are using to catch the event. @Tim

Comment: Nope, didnt find anything. Any other option?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189683/discussion-between-sergejv-and-tim).

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. This website is using vue. So the command is:

```
document.getElementById('account-settings-save-button').__vue__.onClick();
```

Sorry this question wasn't able to be answered by you.

Answer (score -1):

What do you want to do when this button clicked. You must say `onclick="your_code_here"`

Working example fiddle: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jm87wz3v/)

```
<button 
  id="account-settings-save-button" 
  onclick="alert('click event occured')">
   BUTTON
</button>
```

Comment: I don't create the html. I want to write a script which clicks this button a website.

Comment: The functionality is that the website navigates to the next website

Comment: In this case there can be a different problem. 
First are you sure that you are getting the right element with ```getElemenetById```

Comment: To find out you can console.log this  
```console.log('button', document.getElementById('account-settings-save-button'))```